# Problem installing RQDA into R 3.5.3 with R studio. Windows 10

Tags: r, windows-10, data-analysis, rqda

Please help me figure out how to install RQDA onto R 3.5.3 with Rstudio.
I know that some dependencies have been taken off CRAN, so is there anyone who can do a step by step guide on how to install RQDA onto a Windows machine with R3.5.3 and Rstudio?

Comment: You can always get it from the archive: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RQDA/

Comment: Thanks for pitching in. I already had the link to the archived file. The challenge for me isn't where to find it, it's how to go about the installation from R Studio.

Comment: Click "Install", then under "install from" click on "Package Archive File". You will then be asked to locate the location of the archive file to install.